# How to change the width of a QEditor slot?

Tags: quasar-framework

I am using (probably misusing :|) the toolbar of a QEditor to add a `<q-input>`

```
  <q-editor
      model-value="undefined"
      v-model="note.text"
      @click="noteClicked(note)"
      @blur="noteBlurred(note)"
      :toolbar="[['title'], ['tags']]"
  >
    <template v-slot:title>
      <q-input model-value="undefined" v-model="note.title" autofocus dense />
    </template>
    <template v-slot:tags>
      <q-chip v-for="tag in note.tags" removable @remove="removeTag(note, tag)" color="primary" text-color="white" :label="tag">
      </q-chip>
    </template>
  </q-editor>
```

Playground: https://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/yLMKWvJ

I would like to make the `title` slot wider - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a class with `width: 30vw`